# I'm trying PHP Amp client but it's not working, keeps returning error

Tags: php, httpclient

I'm trying Amp client to return page content but it keeps failing. I've installed the package, and trying the example given by the docs.. but I can't figure out why it's not working. Here's the code:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Amp\Http\Client\HttpClientBuilder;

use Amp\Http\Client\Request;
use Amp\Http\Client\Response;
//use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AmpConcurrentRequestsController extends Controller
{
    public function ampTest1()
    {
        $httpClient = HttpClientBuilder::buildDefault();


        $request = new Request('GET', 'http://example.com');
        $promise = $httpClient->request($request);

        /** @var Response $response */
        $response = Amp\wait($promise);


        $statusCode = $response->getStatus();
        $body = yield $response->getBody()->buffer();

    }
}
```

I get this error:

> Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response::setContent(): Argument #1
> ($content) must be of type ?string, Generator given, called in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\laundarySaaS\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Http\Response.php
> on line 72

Comment: What are you expecting this line to do: `$body = yield $response->getBody()->buffer();`

Comment: tbh I'm confused .. I was just trying code after code. Because for some reason I'm trying copying from the docs but it's not working .. what I want I just to send a request and get a response, I want this as a beginning step for bigger things but unfortunate i'm stuck on this.. Before this I tried Guzzle and I stuck on it also..

Comment: I'll give example of what I'm facing. I try the simplest code as following:
`use Amp\Http\Client\HttpClientBuilder;

$client = HttpClientBuilder::buildDefault();

$response = $client->request(new Request("https://httpbin.org/get"));

var_dump($response->getStatus());
var_dump($response->getHeaders());
var_dump($response->getBody()->buffer());`

I get this error:
`Call to undefined method Amp\Coroutine::getStatus()`
now my question where to get this method? if not existed inside the package that is required 1st to run the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What eventually worked for me is below code.

```
public function ampTest1()
    {
        // Create a new HTTP client
        $httpClient = HttpClientBuilder::buildDefault();

        // Send a GET request to the specified URL
        $request = new Request( 'https://example.com');

        $promise = $httpClient->request($request);

        /** @var Response $response */
        $response = Promise\wait($promise);

        // Get the response code
        $code = $response->getStatus();

        // Do something with the response code
        echo $code;
    }
```